# Xamarin Forms ScrollView scrolls automatically to the beginning when any child element is clicked

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, click, scrollview, touch

I created a Horizontal / Vertical Scrollview in Xamarin Forms that contains several types of childs like:

- Labels
- CustomCheckboxes
- ImageViews
- Pickers
- Sliders

[image]

Here is my code:

```
ScrollView scrollTracks = new ScrollView
{
     BackgroundColor = Color.Black,
     VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.StartAndExpand,
     HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
     Content = layoutTracks,
     Orientation = ScrollOrientation.Both
};
```

When I click some child elements like the CustomCheckboxes, or the Labels, or the ImageViews, the program scroll automatically the view to the beginning.

I tested this on the UWP platform.

How can I make the program to stop doing this?

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/597

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this tag to the ScrollView solved my issue:

```
IsTabStop = false
```

Here the code:

```
ScrollView scrollTracks = new ScrollView
{
     BackgroundColor = Color.Black,
     VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.StartAndExpand,
     HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
     Content = layoutTracks,
     Orientation = ScrollOrientation.Both,
     IsTabStop = false
};
```